# I need MATLAB or Mathematica code to solve this integral over limit 0- λ

Tags: computational-physics, software

I want the code to integrate equation(1) or (2) over the limits using mathematical or mathlab to get equation (3) as the answer of $Z$ vibrational partition function, giving the following additional information $$
\begin{aligned}
Z_{v i b}(\beta) &=\sum_{n=0}^{\lambda} e^{-\beta E_{n}}, \quad \beta=\frac{1}{k T}, \\
\lambda &=-c+\sqrt{A} \pm \sqrt{A-B}
\end{aligned}
$$, $$
Z_{v i b}(\beta)=\sum_{n=0}^{\lambda} e^{\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2}}{4 m}(B-2 A)+\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2} B^{2}}{8 m(n+c)^{2}}+\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2}}{8 m}(n+c)^{2}}
$$ In the classical limit, the summation turns to integral
$$
\begin{array}{l}
Z_{v i b}(\beta)=\int_{0}^{\lambda} e^{\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2}}{4 m}(B-2 A)+\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2} B^{2}}{8 m(n+c)^{2}}+\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2}}{8 m}(n+c)^{2}} d n,............(1) \\
=\int_{c}^{\lambda+c} e^{\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2}}{4 m }(B-2 A)+\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2} B^{2}}{8 m \rho^{2}}+\frac{\beta a^{2} \hbar^{2}}{8 m \prime} \rho^{2}} d \rho, \rho=c+n ...........(2)\\
=e^{\beta \Lambda_{3}} \sqrt{\pi}\left[\frac{\left[1-\operatorname{Erf}\left(\Lambda_{1} \sqrt{\beta}\right)\right]-e^{\Lambda_{4} \beta}\left[1-\operatorname{Erf}\left(\Lambda_{2} \sqrt{\beta}\right)\right]}{\Lambda_{5} \sqrt{\beta}}\right]...........(3)
\end{array}
$$

where we have also introduced the following parameters for mathematical simplicity,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\Lambda_{1}=\frac{1}{\rho} \sqrt{-\frac{a^{2} \hbar^{2} B^{2}}{8 m}}-\rho \sqrt{-\frac{a^{2} \hbar^{2}}{8 m}}, \quad \Lambda_{2}=\frac{1}{\rho} \sqrt{-\frac{a^{2} \hbar^{2} B^{2}}{8 m}}+\rho \sqrt{-\frac{a^{2} \hbar^{2}}{8 m}} \\
\Lambda_{3}=-\frac{a^{2} \hbar^{2} A}{2 m}, \Lambda_{4}=\frac{a^{2} \hbar^{2} B}{2 m}, \Lambda_{5}=\sqrt{-2 a^{2} \hbar^{2}}, \quad c \leq \rho \leq c+\lambda
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: To clarify, are you seeking a numeric value for a definite integral or for a series summation?  The phrase "to get equation (3)" suggests symbolic solutions are needed.

Comment: I am seeking a  numerical solution  to this integral using mathlab or Mathematica instead of conventional method of solving calculus by hand